# It's possible to xterm.js on nodejs server side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, terminal, xtermjs

I'm creating a mutiplex terminal on NodeJs, for rendering data to StdOut i'm using [terminal.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/terminal.js/v/1.0.7), but it is a little bit glitchie, so I decide to use [xterm.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xterm) how has a begger community working on it.

But when i try to import xterm.js right on NodeJs, this error accurs:

```
/home/.../node_modules/xterm/lib/webpack:/xterm/webpack/universalModuleDefinition:10
})(self, function() {
   ^
ReferenceError: self is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/.../node_modules/xterm/lib/webpack:/xterm/webpack/universalModuleDefinition:10:4)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1121:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:996:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/.../src/main.ts:1:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:14)
    at Module.m._compile (/home/.../node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1056:23)
```

So, It is a away to use Xterm.Js on server side (nodejs)?

Comment: A fully working nodejs build without a browser env is currently not yet possible. xtermjs is still in transition to a common emulation lib and a browser part for user input and output rendering. There are issues/PRs open in this regard, if you like to help dismantling the deps. Goal is to get a standalone nodejs emulation build, stretched goal would be a worker capable build in the long run. It def. would fit your purpose, but it is not there yet. Until then you can try to bundling on `common/CoreTerminal` (work intensive, will still need tons of shims to mimick `browser/Terminal` parts).

Comment: this is really a shame, but i will be looking forward to it by xterm-core. Thanks for the answer.